# How to make a list filled from database visible in php?

Tags: php

I am taking the values of the course and the semester,and searching in database for the instructors who teach the course at that semester,It worked. But I want the values to be shown in a list after submitting it, I want the list to appear only after submitting.Then I want to choose from the list an instructor and add him in database with the course and the semester selected first,without re selecting them.Please help..

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['courses'] = $_SESSION['semester'] = $coursechosen = $semesterchosen = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    require_once 'connect.php';
    $semester = "";
    $courses = $_GET['courses'];
    $sem = $_GET['sem'];
    $semyr = $_GET['semyr'];
    $semester = $sem . $semyr;

    if (isset($_GET['courses']) && isset($_GET['sem']) && isset($_GET['semyr'])) {

        $_SESSION['courses'] = $courses;
        $_SESSION['semester'] = $semester;
        $instructors = mysql_query("select Instructor_Id from teach where  
        Semester='$semester' AND course_code='$courses' ");

        if (!$instructors) {
            die("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
        }
        $row = mysql_num_rows($instructors);
    }
}
?>
<?php
$instructor = $_GET['instructor'];
if (isset($_SESSION['courses']) && isset($_SESSION['semester'])) {

    $coursechosen = $_SESSION['courses'];
    $semesterchosen = $_SESSION['semester'];

    $query = "Insert INTO coordinators(instructor_id,course_code,semester) 
        VALUES ('$instructor','$coursechosen','$semesterchosen')";
    // $query="Insert INTO instructors(Fname)VALUES('$instructor')";
    mysql_query($query);
}
?>


<form method="get" action="Chairman.php" onsubmit="return
        validate()">

    <select name="courses" id="courses" >
        <option value="courses"><--Courses--></option>
        <option value="PHYS220">Physics for Engineers</option>
        <option value="MATH210">Calculus II</option>
        <option value="MATH225">Linear Algebra with Applications</option>
    </select>

    <select name="sem" id="sem" >
        <option selected="selected">Season</option>
        <option value="Fall">Fall</option>
        <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
        <option value="Summer">Summer</option>
    </select>

    <select name="semyr" id="semyr" >
        <option>Year</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>



        <div> <input type="submit" value="Submit" ></input></div>

        <div>
            <select name="instructor">
<?php
if ($row !== 0) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < $row;  ++$i) {

        $instructor_id = mysql_fetch_array($instructors);
        $instructorsname = mysql_query("select * from instructors where  
              Id='$instructor_id[0]'");
        $rowname = mysql_num_rows($instructorsname);


        $instructorsnames = mysql_fetch_array($instructorsname);
        echo "<option
              value='$instructorsnames[0]'>" . $instructorsnames['Fname'] . " 
              " . $instructorsnames['Lname'] . "</option>";
    }
}
?>
            </select>
        </div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly and where you stucked up ?

Comment: Not related to your problem but I wouldn't go to the database inside a loop.  Instead of echoing inside your loop I would probably build up an array of html strings, and then echo an implode().

Comment: I want the list to be shown only after submitting the course and the semester.In this code it is displayed empty first,then after submitting it if filled.

Comment: Return everything and do some post processing in PHP.

Comment: I solved the problem,  I made the instructor select list with a submit button in a different form.and It worked

Answer (score 0):

[`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) returns an array with your data. So, to show instructors, you have to iterate through your list and write them out. Try:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    echo "<option value='$row['id']'>".$row['Fname']." 
      ".$row['Lname']."</option>";

}
```

That should give you a list of option. But I'm not quite sure if I understood what your question is. If that doesn't answer it, could you be more specific?

Comment: I don't want the select list to be shown only when i press submit.I don't want the select list to be shown before I press submit

Comment: did you know what I really want?

Comment: I tried this,but though the $row=0  it is showing me empty select list<?php  
          $row = mysql_num_rows($instructors);
          if($row!==0){
              echo "<select name='instructor'>"; ?>

Comment: Okay, so you don't want to submit your form. You can use javascript to show the select once you hit "submit", and afterwards submit your form once users select instructors. Did I get it right this time?

Comment: yess somehow,only one problem how will i get the values of the instructor list? instructors depend on the course and semester list

Comment: I am doing a website project for our university, which is an online quiz and assessment website, Iam supposed to allow the dean to search for instructors from database who teach a course he select it at a specific semester and then add him as a coordinator.

Comment: I solved the problem,  I made the instructor select list with a submit button in a different form.and It worked

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. However, I guess you could use [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) in order to build your page with only one form. And sooner or later, working with web, you'll have to use ajax so better sooner!